# Bitwise shift to get max unsigned value

Tags: java, bit-manipulation

I need to generate max value for unsigned 64 bit long in java, using bitwise shift. So here is my function:

```
public static final boolean isMaxLimitMiss(int bitsCount, BigDecimal value, int signum) {
    if (signum == 0) {
        BigDecimal val = new BigDecimal(Long.valueOf((1 << (bitsCount)) - 1));

        return Long.compareUnsigned(value.longValue(), val.longValue()) > 0 ? true : false;
    }

    return value.compareTo(new BigDecimal((1L << (bitsCount - 1)) - 1)) > 0 ? true : false;
}
```

It just checks that ***value*** is in range for max value that ***bitsCount*** provides.
It works fine for signed data.
In case 64 bit, and for unsigned (Yes, there are no unsigned long in java. I trying to simulate it) - it is  incorrect. `((1 << (bitsCount)) - 1` evaluates to 0

How can I pass *value = 2^64 - 1* into BigDecimal constructor?

Comment: Your question is awfully unclear, you are using terminology "unsigned 64 bit long" (which does not exist in java) without clearly defining purpose, expected input and output. Also, try asking a *clear* question; don't make the reader *guess* the question.

Comment: @Durandal They are using the new Java 8 unsigned comparison ([`Long#compareUnsigned`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#compareUnsigned-long-long-)) which compares a signed number as if it were unsigned.

Comment: @Radiodef How does that observation obviate the need for a clear question statement? (after all the OP clarified the question to be unrelated to the method?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One first thing:

```
(1 << (bitsCount)) - 1
```

This is a mistake because you are only performing integer arithmetic. You needed:

```
(1L << (bitsCount)) - 1
```

But anyway I assume `bitsCount` is 64. In Java you cannot shift by a number larger than 63 for a long and 31 for an int ([JLS 15.19](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.19)):

> If the promoted type of the left-hand operand is `int`, only the five lowest-order bits of the right-hand operand are used as the shift distance. It is as if the right-hand operand were subjected to a bitwise logical `AND` operator `&` (§15.22.1) with the mask value `0x1f` (`0b11111`). The shift distance actually used is therefore always in the range `0` to `31`, inclusive.
>
> If the promoted type of the left-hand operand is `long`, then only the six lowest-order bits of the right-hand operand are used as the shift distance. It is as if the right-hand operand were subjected to a bitwise logical `AND` operator `&` (§15.22.1) with the mask value `0x3f` (`0b111111`). The shift distance actually used is therefore always in the range `0` to `63`, inclusive.

This is why you get 0, because the expression is reduced to `(1 << 0) - 1`.

You need to compute your max value a different way, for example:

```
-1L >>> (64 - bitsCount)
```

or:

```
BigInteger.ONE.shiftLeft(bitsCount).subtract(BigInteger.ONE)
```

If you are testing a BigDecimal it would be safer to not use long at all here.

Comment: Can you advice how to pass unsigned 64 bit value to BigInteger constructor ?